# Showing Chemical reaction on websites?

Tags: chemfig

I have been writing latex code for showing chemical reactions thorugh chemfig . Now i want to show it in website . The only solution i find is to capture screenshot crop it and publish it ? Is there any better way than this?

I found the way to show maths equation just by code like using mathml etc. But i still cannot find way to show chemical reaction using codes ?

Is there anyway or i should stick to boring screenshot idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect you refer to MathJax (as seen on Math.SX). I'm not sure whether this is covered by TeX.SX.

Comment: If you want to draw your images in latex, compile them individually, and then use them on the websites, maybe the `standalone` package with the convert to png option is suitable...

Comment: related: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/5954/17423

Comment: If you happen to have a WordPress blog you can use the [QuickLaTeX plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-quicklatex/) (see also [its homepage](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/)). The examples in [this post on my blog](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2011/11/a-small-exercise/) are all rendered by the plugin, I just typed the LaTeX code...

Comment: @clemens Yes thanks for the plugins . Is there something like php script for compiling latex code ?

Answer (score 3):

Create a document that contains the formula and nothing else. Compile it to a pdf file, and then convert it to png using `pdftoppm`.

Create the document containing the formula, called `chem.tex` like this:

```
\documentclass[margin=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{ * 6((=O)-N(-CH_3)- *
5(-N=-N(-CH_3)-=)--(=O)-N(-H_3C)-)}
\end{document}
```

then run `pdflatex chem.tex; pdftoppm -r 600 -png chem.pdf chem.png`.

If you want a svg file, which most browsers support, replace the last command with `pdf2svg chem.pdf chem.svg`

This should output this image:
[image: Chemical formula for caffeine]

of course, you can create a simple script that does this automatically.

Comment: why  pdf -> svg -> png? 1. you can use svgs in most (every?) browser, second if you need a png you can just do `pdftoppm -r <resolution> -png <inputfile> <outputfile>`. Also using the `standalone` class the pdfcrop command becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the pdftoppm command, i did not notice it. I tried the standalone class, but it crops the picture too much, the O at the top is cut. Is there any way to specify a margin with the `standalone` class?

Comment: Yes,  there is a `margin=dimen` class option

Answer (score 3):

`chemfig` is based on `tikz` and it is converted to `svg` images with `tex4ht`.

If we use example from `G.P.`'s answer, we get this result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{ * 6((=O)-N(-CH_3)- *
5(-N=-N(-CH_3)-=)--(=O)-N(-H_3C)-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

using

```
htlatex filename command
```

this solution has advantage that you can create your whole page in LaTeX.